# Cognito validation SAML - what is userName constraint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml, amazon-cognito, endpoint

I'm calling the SAML authorization endpoint on my Cognito user pool and once I log in through my other provider, I get this error when redirecting back to my website:

`Error in SAML response processing: 1 validation error detected: Value ' ... ... ' at 'userName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 128`

What constraint is this? I don't see any documentation about this particular constraint. And how can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-attribute-mapping.html

I assume this is why:

> Currently, only the Facebook id, Google sub, and Login with Amazon user_id attributes can be mapped to the Amazon Cognito User Pools username attribute.
>
> The attribute in the user pool must be large enough to fit the values of the mapped identity provider attributes, or an error occurs when users sign in. Custom attributes should be set to the maximum 2048 character size if mapped to identity provider tokens.

Comment: So which attribute is mapped from SAML to the username attribute?

Comment: The default NameID is used for the mapping. So their docs are not technically correct, since OIDC and SAML do map to the default username attribute (you just can't seem to change that thru the mapping interface even if you provide a custom mapping). I ended up asking the SAML IdP I was using to change which value they provided to the Cognito SP (as the default NameID).

Comment: @AndrewKarpenko Which value did you ask them to use instead of the default one?

Comment: @nmarchini It's up to you. It just has to be unique to the individual and not be changeable (otherwise it will break the identity relationship when changed). E.g. you should map to the employee ID, versus employee Last Name. See the NameID formats here for example https://wiki.cac.washington.edu/display/infra/Guide+to+NameID+Formats+and+Attributes+Available+from+the+UW+IdP Your IdP may be different.